# Existence of an array of positive numbers.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have the following question:
Does there exist an array $(a_{i,k_n})_{1\leq i\leq k_n,n}$, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}k_n=\infty$, of positive numbers such that
\begin{align*}
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{k_n}a_{i,k_n} &= c_1\\
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{k_n}a^2_{i,k_n} &= c_2\\
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{k_n}a^l_{i,k_n} &= 0, \quad l\geq 3,
\end{align*}
where $0<c_1,c_2<\infty$.

Thank you !

Comment: Well for the 1st equation kn = n , an = 1/n^3      isn't good ?

Comment: @ Itay.V I didnt get what the array you are suggesting looks like. Could you please be more precise.

Comment: Isn't the last summation a summation of positive numbers?

Comment: @Gaffney Yes, the numbers are positive, but since we are dealing with an array, in each line we have a new sequence of numbers, so the series may converge to zero. Take for instance k_n=n, a_(i,n) = 1/n^2.

Comment: the $\ell_1$ norm is larger than the $\ell_2$ norm, so you at least need $c_1\geq c_2$. For $c_1>c_2$, it seems reasonable.

Comment: @Dunham yes, $c_1\geq c_2$ is necessary for the existence of such an array.